# flatMap() in Scala during recursion

Tags: scala

I was going through a Scala-99 problem to reduce a complex nested list into a flat list. Code given below:

```
def flatten(l: List[Any]): List[Any] =  l flatMap {
  case ms:List[_] => flatten(ms)
  case l => List(l)
}
val L = List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8)))
val flattenedList = flatten(L)
```

For the given input above `L`, I understood this problem by drawing a tree (given below)

```
List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8)))                            (1)
|                \             \ 
List(1, 1)       List(2)    List(3, List(5, 8))                     (2)
|        \                       |        \ 
List(1)  List(1)              List(3)     List(5, 8)                (3)
                                                 |   \
                                            List(5)  List(8)        (4)
```

What I've understood is that, the program results in the leaf nodes being added in a list maintained by Scala internally, like:

```
li = List(List(1), List(1), List(2), List(3), List(5), List(8))
```

and then the result is passed to the flatten method which results in the final answer:

```
List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
```

**Is my understanding correct?**

EDIT: I'm sorry, I forgot to add this:

I wanted to ask that if my understanding is correct then why does replacing `flatMap` with `map` in the `flatten`'s definition above produces this list:

```
List(List(List(1), List(1)), List(2), List(List(3), List(List(5), List(8))))
```

I mean isn't `flatMap` just `map` then `flatten`. Shouldn't I be getting like the one I mentioned above:

```
li = List(List(1), List(1), List(2), List(3), List(5), List(8))
```

Comment: `Any` is symptom a design issue, guess a tailrec would be nice

Comment: Yes it is correct. Literally saying you have Depth First Search implemented here in `flatten` method.

Comment: Thanks @IvanKurchenko. I have a silly?!? doubt which I have added as an edit, could you please help answer it as well?

Comment: That's not correct. flatMap on a List will give you a flattened List, but will not break the items out of the enclosing List like you thought., so `List(List(1,1))` in your example will give `List(List(1), List(1))` but it still has an enclosing List. If you wanna break them out, you need to do flatMap on outer List

Comment: @texasbruce I know how flatMap functions in a normal way but this "recursive functioning" is certainly not helping me. I mean is the `flatten` part also being applied recursively, so for example, after the `map` part breaks `List(1, 1)` into List(List(1), List(1)) then `flatten` converts it back into `List(1, 1)` ?!?! What purpose will that serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that `flatMap`is just `map` and `flatten` but note that this `flatten` is not the same `flatten` you define, for list it only concatenate inner lists at 1 level.
One very useful way to unpack these is to use substitution model, just like maths

if I define it like this, (calling it f to avoid confusion with flatten here and flatten in std library)

```scala
def f(l: List[Any]): List[Any] =  l map {
  case ms:List[_] => f(ms)
  case l => List(l)
}
```

then

```
f(List(  List(1,    1),    2))
= List(f(List(1,    1)), f(2)) // apply f to element of the outer most list
= List(List(f(1), f(1)), f(2)) // apply f to element of the inner list
= List(List(List(1), List(1)), List(2))) // no more recursion
```

Notice `map` doesn't change the structure of your list, it only applies the function to each element. This should explains how you have the result if you replace `flatMap` with `map`

Now if you have `flatMap` instead of `map`, then the `flatten` step is simply concatenating

```scala
def f(l: List[Any]): List[Any] =  l flatMap {
  case ms:List[_] => f(ms)
  case l => List(l)
}
```

then

```
f(List(List(1,1), 2))
= f(List(1,1))         ++ f(2) // apply f to each element and concatenate
= (f(1) ++ f(1))       ++ f(2)
= (List(1) ++ List(1)) ++ List(2)
= List( 1,1)           ++ List(2)
= List(1,2,3)
```

or in another way, using flatten instead of ++

```
f(        List(     List(1,1),    2))
= flatten(List( f(      List(  1,    1)) , f(2))) // map and flatten
= flatten(List( flatten(List(f(1), f(1))), f(2))) // again map and flatten
= flatten(List( flatten(List(List(1), List(1))), List(2))))
```

now you can see that `flatten` is called multiple times, at every level where you recursively apply `f` which will collapse your tree 1 level at a time into just 1 big list.

To answer your comment: why is `List(1,1)` is turned into `flatten(List(List(1), List(1))`. It's because this is the simple case, but consider `List(1, List(2))`, then `f` will be applied for `1` and `List(2)`. Because the next step is to 'flatten' (in stdlib) then both `1` & `List(2)` must be turned into a List so that it is in the right shape